# TSQL -Eliminating Duplicates from ResultSet and combining them in a single row

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a table called **employee** with following fields

```
Id | Name     | PrimaryEmail1  | PrimaryEmail2 | PrimaryEmail3
1  | JonSkeet | NULL           | NULL          | jonskeet@test.com
1  | JonSkeet | NULL           | Jon@test.com  | jonskeet@test.com
1  | JonSkeet | skeet@test.com | NULL          | jonskeet@test.com
2  | George   | G1@Test.com    | NULL          | NULL
2  | George   | NULL           | G2@test.com   | NULL
2  | George   | NULL           | NULL          | G3@test.com
```

How to write a TSQL query so that i can obtain the following resultset?

```
Id | Name     | PrimaryEmail1  | PrimaryEmail2 | PrimaryEmail3
1  | JonSkeet | skeet@test.com | jon@test.com  | jonskeet@test.com
2  | George   | G1@test.com    | G2@test.com   | G3@test.com
```

Comment: What is you had different values for PrimaryEmail3 for JonSkeet ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MAX will eliminate NULLs

```
SELECT
   ID, Name, 
   MAX(PrimaryEmail1) AS PrimaryEmail1,
   MAX(PrimaryEmail2) AS PrimaryEmail2, 
   MAX(PrimaryEmail3) AS PrimaryEmail3
FROM
   employee 
GROUP BY
   ID, Name
```

However, your example for JonSkeet shows PrimaryEmail3 is the same. Will you ever expect different values per ID+Name? If so, you can't combine into a single row unless you choose the MAX one (or MIN even).

This assumes that Id-Name pairs are consistent too

Comment: Yes I got the expected result from your query.Thanks.I am unable to edit my question as it shows some format errors.Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The following script will concatenate all distinct non-NULL emails into a single list, separately for every column:

```
;
WITH employee (Id, Name, PrimaryEmail1, PrimaryEmail2, PrimaryEmail3) AS (
  SELECT 1, 'JonSkeet', NULL            , NULL          , 'jonskeet@test.com' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'JonSkeet', NULL            , 'Jon@test.com', 'jonskeet@test.com' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'JonSkeet', 'skeet@test.com', NULL          , 'jonskeet@test.com' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'George'  , 'G1@Test.com'   , NULL          , NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'George'  , NULL            , 'G2@test.com' , NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'George'  , NULL            , NULL          , 'G3@test.com'
)

SELECT
  Id,
  Name,
  PrimaryEmail1 = SUBSTRING(
    (SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + PrimaryEmail1 FROM employee WHERE Id = e.Id FOR XML PATH ('')),
    3,
    999999
  ),
  PrimaryEmail2 = SUBSTRING(
    (SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + PrimaryEmail2 FROM employee WHERE Id = e.Id FOR XML PATH ('')),
    3,
    999999
  ),
  PrimaryEmail3 = SUBSTRING(
    (SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + PrimaryEmail3 FROM employee WHERE Id = e.Id FOR XML PATH ('')),
    3,
    999999
  )
FROM employee e
GROUP BY Id, Name
```

If there can never be distinct non-NULL values in any of the three `PrimaryEmail` columns for the same employee, you will get the same result as with `MIN` or `MAX`. Otherwise you will get all the distinct values in a list

Results for the above script:

```
Id Name     PrimaryEmail1  PrimaryEmail2 PrimaryEmail3     
-- -------- -------------- ------------- ----------------- 
1  JonSkeet skeet@test.com Jon@test.com  jonskeet@test.com 
2  George   G1@Test.com    G2@test.com   G3@test.com
```